# Move search to the top center of stackoverflow and all other sites?

Tags: feature-request, search

Search is a very important mechanism and tool in sites like this.  Amazon and various other sites put an emphasis on search by pretty much slapping it at the top, making it larger and ensuring that is one of the end user's focal points when they hit the site.

This type of design drives users to search immediately.  I see a lot of duplicate questions being asked and being closed.  We need to emphasise search more and I believe moving it to the top center of the site and styling it a bit more will help.

**Why do I believe this?**

From my own experience we used to run a rather large CRM type system at my workplace.  The old CRM system we were using had a similar search mechanism to what we use on stackoverflow, top right.  What ended up happening is search was barely ever used.  In fact, instead of searching people were constantly creating records that were very similar if not duplicates to what already existed.

About 6 months ago we implemented a new crm type system and we made the decision to move the search bar to sit at the top of the page in the center and styled it so we had a larger text box with some css magic.  We made search a focal point on our system...and although the users made us work hard to make it work better (We use elastic search) we noticed people were using it more and more.

The result is more and more people use search before they even decide to create any type of record.  I believe this would help so and the various other stackexchange sites.

## What we did

We went from this sitting on the top right corner:

[image]

To this simply sitting in the center and styled:

[image]

Now our user's main focus is simply search.  Our numbers backed this up as we were logging the events of the search, (when the search was made, number of clicks, number of distinct searches, etc. etc).

Comment: Aren't there some UX reports that will back this up?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I dont have any standard reports, what I am saying is we have our own internal reports and this is the best way to get people to search.  We had search before on the top right, small just like stackexchange - it doesn't work.  Our numbers prove it for our case but I look at it from a UX element, if it was designed and styled to be a larger centered textbox it would shift people's focus.  I am not a css person but I'll screen shot what we did and post it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you mean something along the lines of this I completely agree with you.

[image]

Comment: +1 - This is close to what I mean, but I believe it could use a small tweaking of the CSS to make it stand out more.  Otherwise it simply looks like a small input box.

Comment: Yeah I agree, this is all I could be bother to edit :p. I agree it should be bigger, make sure people know that the first thing you should do is search.

Comment: It works wonders on sites that emphasis it.  Stackoverflow and in fact all stackexchange sites need to emphasize search.  I know its there at the top but just moving it to the center and styling it may work wonders.  I think this would make using search more intuitive to the typical end user.

Answer (score 2):

If this is about getting people to search for their question before they ask it, I think you'll get better results by focusing your efforts on the question-asking workflow.

For instance, Quora has a single page that asks for a specific title.  The title box is pretty much all there is on that page.  Then they AJAX in question titles that are similar, and ask the user if any of the questions are the same as theirs.  The user must specifically indicate on the page that none of the existing titles are the same question.

We do something similar, but we do it atop the question-asking box, where people can ignore it and just go on to asking their question.

Comment: That's fine and this is a nice feature which I personally use as well, but I much prefer to have more emphasis on search.  Anyhow +1 for pointing out what does currently exist.

Comment: I like your suggestion anyway, and have upvoted it.  I may raise this issue as a separate feature request.