# Give greater dominance/placement to searching rather than asking for new/low rep users

Tags: feature-request, search, homepage

**TL;DR**: We are more than just another *Yahoo Answers* or forum, but we are presenting ourselves in exactly the same way; just another Q&A site. Although technically correct, due to our rules and organization we're a lot more than that. Right now it's possible to find answers to most, if not all, beginner questions on SO. **We've have become one of the best, if not the best, programmer's resource and the same is true for some of the other network sites. The problem is that by giving the 'Ask Question'-flow dominant care and placement we're actually motivating new users to ask their questions rather than search for answers.** This is a direct consequence of the structure and setup of the site, not of "lazy newcomers" or "*help vampires*" and can be solved by giving the search flow *far* more dominant placement and care (see mockups below) specifically for very low rep and guest users.

---

I have read through various discussions regarding the problem of "*help vampires*", users that simply ask questions, doing nearly no troubleshooting of their own and not contributing back to the community. Although I do not believe they are that big of a problem on their own, I do agree that it's a bit sad how right now 3 out of 4 questions I see on the homepage that are asked by users with rep under 50 are answerable using a simple Google search *limited to StackOverflow questions* (and the fourth could be answered by combining two other questions).

We already have the content, and yet we spend a lot of time and effort closing and answering the same questions over and over and over again. Now, rather than just complaining I was thinking how one could possibly solve this issue and one thing that hit me is to make the Stack Overflow homepage a true search homepage with the search box up front and centre **for very low rep (<15 or so) and new users**.  Additionally it would also be good to give the search bar a more dominant placing on the question pages, once again primarily or only for low rep or guest users. This would come along with hiding user interface elements such as 'Ask Question', 'Top Questions', 'Users', 'Badges', 'Unanswered' and maybe even the 'Hot Network Questions'.

So, just to make it clear I made a screenshot of the current homepage:

[image: The way the current homepage looks on StackOverflow.com]

And what I am proposing would be something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dswob.png). Or, in response to an answer by Sam, one could add a link to the Q&A/Social homepage as well like such (which I believe is an excellent idea/point):

[image: The way a cleaned up homepage would look, including a link back to the Q&A Homepage]

And only on the search results page or the Q&A homepage would the option be shown to ask your question. In previous versions of this question I wrote that I could not think of any situations where one could wish to ask a question as a new user without first searching. The interesting point has been made by Cerbrus that a user who has searched previously and then comes back to the site will have searched already and knows the answer is not on the site. A possible solution *could* be to show the button based on previous search habits which could be stored client side without an account. Now, *personally* I think the link to the Q&A homepage is more than enough, but this could definitely be something to consider.

Another point that has been raised is that a lot of new users don't access the SO page through the homepage (though those who come from Google are probably already a smaller "problem"), so a redesign like this would be in line with changes to the homepage:

[image: The way a question page could look with a bigger focus on search]

The 'Ask a Question' option could definitely not be removed as the user likely already came from Google, however changing the priority of the UI elements could get a lot of users into the search flow first rather than the *ask a question* flow. Additionally showing the Q&A info banner might not be necessary any more which would clean up the design a lot as well.

## Advantages

- New users will have consciously searched the site. It will not take a lot more work than the current Ask Question process, but it will be a two step process where instead of in a small box inside the form the similar questions are shown full size and the mental expectations of the user are different ("I am going to ask my question" vs "I am searching for an answer to my problem, maybe I will have to ask it myself").
- For a lot of established programming languages all simple questions have been asked already. This is something I have been realizing more and more lately, but it is kind of true. Even for some of the more obscure languages. New users tend to have questions about popular languages rather than exotic libraries or languages, so improving the search experience should be more important than improving the *ask a question* and *moderation* processes on which a **lot** of time is spent.

## Issues to consider

- The current search engine is far from good (at least IMHO which is shared with other users directing new users to Google rather than SO search; some others (see below) disagree). It would either need rebuilding or, for example, one could try contacting Google about whether they'd like to support StackOverflow with 'Google Search for Enterprises'. *This discussion is out of scope for this feature request/proposal and there are other questions discussing various aspects of the search engine and presentation.* However even with the current engine and system a redesign like this could be extremely valuable.
- Changing the homepage only makes real sense for SE sites after they reach a certain amount of content, which is hard to define. SO definitely has enough content to make this a worthwhile change and the same is true for some of the other sites on the network. There are however also sites that will never reach this point, either because they strongly deviate from the SE formula (codereview.SE, codegolf.SE, puzzling.SE) or because the number of theoretical questions that can be asked on a topic is just too ridicilously big (e.g. patents.SE). Either way, this can be easily be determined by looking up what percentage of questions get closed as duplicates per site. The issue however is that implementing this would make SO (and possibly other sites) deviate from the rest of the SE sites. This could be seen as reaching the next level of maturity, but it will be on odds with the current homogeneity.

So, yeah, just an idea I had, glad to see many in the community agree.

Comment: My two cents: if you hide the Ask Question button in the search results page, some (of the more problematic) users will search for garbage in order to get results (*any* results) and the button they're looking for. Example of average search query: `qsdlqjsfhmqlsfjmqsfgk`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: If they already know that then they already asked a question before ;-) And those users are likely to already have build up reputation as well then and get the normal homepage. I am talking about the users who don't have 'bad' intentions in the first place, but simply ask the same simple question that has already been asked before. I don't mean this as a foolproof system, but even with a query you're describing no harm is done and yet a lot of duplicates might have already been caught.

Comment: That will become common knowledge after some time ("go to Stack Overflow, but remember you have to search something in order to ask a question"). I have a feeling the correlation between searching and asking will be missed by many, and they will only see this as an inconvenience.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: New users tend to be predominantly people working on their own, so I am not sure how such knowledge would spread without them being part of the SO community as well. Either way, as I wrote in the proposal, I am open to keeping the link in, just think the main flow should be through search.

Comment: (Ach, so hate it when there is an answer, you write some quality comment on it, and then the answer is deleted... if you change position then just change your answer or something...)

Comment: Change the answer, and still "suffer" from the downvote train that's usually incoming once you've got `-1/2`. If a answer's completely changed, I feel it's more productive to just replace the answer. In this case, I have nothing to add ad the moment, though. I'd suggest keeping the frontpage as it is, but just adding a large search block to it (About the size of that gray-ish block, perhaps?).

Comment: @Cerbrus: That's the nice thing about meta, downvotes tend to just mean disagreement, not dislike. No reputation 'harmed' either :P

Comment: I know it doesn't change my rep, but I still get the idea that people tend to agree with the current vote on the answer. But that's a discussion for a different question.

Comment: even though I love the idea I already know there is not even 1% chance this will get implemented...

Comment: I thought a vampire (here) was someone who helped the people asking bad questions...

Comment: @Poldie: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem

Comment: Nice idea with the redesign. Certainly an improvement.

Comment: I like the Search field & _"Or ask..."_ link. This should give users a strong suggestion to search first, like we want to.

Comment: I would be very curious to see that in action. I'm quite pessimistic about the results, but that can be worked around with nice, hard numbers if this gets implemented.

Comment: For best results, have it be powered by Google Custom Search.

Comment: @BoltClock: Google Custom Search looks terrible, however Google being a pretty open software company I wouldn't be surprised if you could get them to share Google Search for Enterprises for free or a extremely reduced price.

Comment: Related(?): [Replace the built-in Elastic Search with results from Google instead](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254093/456814).

Comment: @Cupcake: Yep, definitely related, was planning to link it in the disadvantages section, but next couldn't find it quickly enough so forgot about it :) + the 'solution' they mention is Google Custom search which is kinda weak as I expressed above~

Comment: @DavidMulder _Google being a pretty open software company_, huh?  Do you have any clue about the terms of Google Enterprise Search Appliance?  Go, enlighten yourself.

Comment: @devnull: Hey, I know it's *meant* for awefully serious businesses and all that, but don't forget there are a **lot** of Googlers here on SO. And from the people I have chatted with who work for Google they are still pretty loose about a lot of stuff, so yeah, if there's any company I wouldn't be surprised pulling something like this for the sake of getting a lot of good RL rep and as a way of thanks, it's Google. Either way, that discussion was supposed to be out of scope for this proposal. There are a **lot** of other ways to improve the search itself as well.

Comment: Facts: (1) When asking a question, there's a list that pops up.  Despite the _poor search_, on several occasions one (or more) of those questions contain the answer.  The question is still posted.  (2) Numerous questions that could have been answered by a cursory glance at the documentation continue to be posted.  (3) Numerous questions that could have been answered by a simple web search continue to be posted.  When on Earth makes you think that _an improved search_ would lead to such silly questions not being asked (and answered)?

Comment: On a side note, those maintaining the site wouldn't want to _discourage_ anybody to post a FAQ.  Neither would the rep whores want that.  That is the precise reason that dups are often answered by those having the new _insta-close_ powers.  It boils down to reputation for users and traffic for the site maintainers.

Comment: There are probably a good number of developers at Google that occasionally get an answer from this site. They'd love to help!

Comment: @devnull making it easy to do things right increases the likeliness of things done right. The opposite is true as well and we should do both (easy for right, hard for wrong).

Comment: @devnull: That's what I mean with SO presenting itself as just another Q&A site, it feels all right to ask just any question because we're presenting ourselves that way. If we present ourselves as a resource rather then a place to ask every question you have, then indeed I believe there will be a mentality change. So, no, it's not the improved search that changes anything, it's the way you present yourself.

Comment: @DavidMulder What's your oppinion on [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/t4k90.png)?

Comment: @Sam: Very much WA inspired and not sure the tag links are that important in the first place as it will now once again get users in the Q&A flow rather than the search flow as they would simply click on the language their problem is in... which brings them to the top questions in that language which doesn't help them in any way. At WA it actually serves a purpose by teaching the user 'all' possibilities of the engine. Additionally I wouldn't call that button 'home', nor make it a full button. As I outlined in my post that should definitely not be the default place to go, just an option.

Comment: @DavidMulder Right I see, so maybe something on the lines of [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YyVwq.png) then?

Comment: @Sam: How do you envision the advanced search to work then? Just curious, as at least right now the advanced search panel is just a set of plain text tips.

Comment: @DavidMulder I was thinking something similar to [Google's advanced search](https://www.google.co.uk/advanced_search?q=).

Comment: @Sam: I am amazed, I didn't realize that page was still around. Even Google itself isn't linking to it any more on their homepage.  Either way, allow me to ask a question, what is it you dislike about the mockup in the question? Indeed it is quite minimalistic and all that, but your last option is as well, plus I don't think any features are missing. So yeah, quite curious.

Comment: @DavidMulder Personally I feel we're not "showing off" the site enough with the current designs, it seems *very* simple, as if there's no connection with the actual information (posts) like the current design. After all, there are over 20 million posts. WA gave some inspiration as how that might be achieved, but as you said that will probably end up misleading users down the same old flow again. The current mockups aren't that bad, it's probably just me, I've never been too keen on very minimalist UIs.

Comment: Honest question-  why do you think they'd ever search?  If I want to search for the answer to a question, I'm not coming to SO.  I'm going to google, and it may bring me to SO.  But an SO explicit search is a waste of time-  if we have the answer, google will find it.  And if they aren't willing to google, they aren't going to search here either.  So all you're doing is reducing the usability of the site to no gain.

Comment: @GabeSechan: A user does what a user is offered. I think a lot of users start with a search on google, the first result might not have been what they were looking for, but it's a link to StackOverflow and they see they can ask questions here... so they do. Regardless of whether the second result would have answered their question or not. That's one half and the other half (with overlap) is users who feel like SO is just another Yahoo Answers, where any questions go: end of story.

Comment: @GabeSechan By giving search dominant placement I do think this can change the mindset of users. Not perfectly, but definitely noticeably. I mean, what the user in the end wants is not "to ask a question", it is to "solve their problem". So giving them guidance in what the right way is to "solve their problem" is the way to go. And directing them to Search would be the first step to it (or allow LMGTFY links again, but those are taboo here).

Comment: The point in [How can we encourage close voters to use their powers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261419/how-can-we-encourage-close-voters-to-use-their-powers/) is interesting.  At times, it appears that some (?) of these _new_ users are sock puppets.

Comment: I posted this quite some time ago: very related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256614/move-search-to-the-top-center-of-stackoverflow-and-all-other-sites

Comment: @JonH: Easy to miss: but linked to it on Cerbrus answer as well already in a comment :) But indeed, I think the design in the first answer is absolutely excellent graphically, but in this question the focus lies on the way the interaction between the search flow and question flow work and their relative dominance.

Comment: I 100% agree with this! Too many times I've made a duplicate question because I asked the question in a completely different way than how the related question was phrased. Then I feel like an idiot and ask myself "how are you so good at searching for these related questions that I couldn't find?" SO inclines the user to ask a question before searching for an answer. So if a user asks a question and doesn't find a related one they assume their question hasn't been answered when in reality they just haven't phrased it the right way.

Answer (score 70):

I think this is a great idea, it should definitely be implemented. Giving greater dominance to searching rather than asking is such a simple solution; lower dupe count, more effort required, cleaner front page UI, etc. Overall I certainly agree, the site does need to be displayed differently.

A few suggestions/ideas though,

- <strike>Personally I think the UI is a little too clean, maybe something like [Wolfram Alpha's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) home page style could be used, with top questions (or [tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4k90.png)) in the background instead? (Of course minimalism is the current UI trend. So this isn't an absolute "must-have", only a suggestion.)</strike> As David [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261343/make-the-search-flow-rather-than-qa-flow-the-primary-flow-for-new-users#comment47333_261343) implementing this idea may lead users to slip back to the current Q/A flow, rather than encouraging them to search.
- There must be an **easy** way to get to the original home page, *even if the user is new or has low rep*. (So users can get to the "Ask Question" button quicker from the search page.)
- I'd also suggest that posts should be more formally displayed (especially to non-users), treating a Q/A pair not as "just a couple of posts", but rather a *community maintained record of information*. This will help users to better understand that the site is different, we're not another forum, we're not another Yahoo Answers. We are Stack Overflow! (Again only a suggestion, I'd like to hear your feedback on this one.)

Comment: `'I want to ask'` <-- I think it's going to be difficult to validate the search for a valid question. Other than that, this is a nice middle road.

Comment: Not a bad idea btw, regarding the link to the original homepage. It does make it a lot easier to get to the ask a question button, but it's still a link that should definitely be included at the very least during the first year such a homepage would be implemented. Added it to the mockups as well.

Comment: I posted this some time ago: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256614/move-search-to-the-top-center-of-stackoverflow-and-all-other-sites

Answer (score 12):

I don't know that I support the entire homepage changing. That seems drastic.

However. For new users, it is an open question — **why doesn't the /ask page, for new users, basically require that they do a search before asking?** I think there's so much opportunity to improve the /ask page to interactively teach new users how to ask better questions, and to teach them how to search before asking, perhaps by guiding them through their first search, interactively. (Maybe even, for the very inexperienced developers, direct them to places where they can learn more?)

Doing this on the /ask page [is more of a "Just In Time" solution](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-just-in-time-theory/). Let people freely browse on the homepage, click around and explore tags and questions, but once they get down to the brass tacks of asking, once they have indicated intent to ask … guide new users into search and so forth via a revamped /ask page.

Comment: The thing to realize is that by the time the user clicked anything with a label like 'Ask Question' it's mentally to late to convince a lot of those users to put in a serious effort in to searching for an answer to their question. If all you would is revampt the '/ask' page then you should at the very least rename all the links to the page 'Search & Ask Question' (which I personally believe an illogical combination, which is why instead I wrote this proposal putting search front and center as the core feature of a knowledge base)

Comment: Search front and center doesn't really make sense to me, and such a drastic change would never go through. Browsing is what you want people to do first, to get a sense of what's here. As for the ask page, if search is required (for new users), it's required -- there is no getting around it.

Comment: I would also add that directly cloning Google's search UI seems like a spectacularly bad idea. We work in _harmony_ with Google, we never replace it. Why broadcast a harmful message out into the universe?

Comment: If I would be allowed to ask, why do you think putting search front and center doesn't make sense? I mean, the homepage part is extreme for sure, but improving the UI of the top right of each page seems pretty conservative. Especially when taking into consideration the new documentation features this seems even downright natural. And copying Google's search UI was just to get the idea across, I am not a graphics designer :) .

Comment: And just wondering, but do new users actually browse the site in that sense? As in, I just can't imagine a new user to open the stackoverflow homepage and being interested in whatever random question is popular right now. That works for most SE network sites due to their far smaller domain, but seems quite an odd position to take with SO.

Comment: Not at all. Do you open the newspaper and wonder what all that meaningless news is doing splashed across the front page? Don't we also judge publications by what appears on their cover? How would anyone know what Stack does without some live real world examples to look at and ponder?

Answer (score 6):

I like the idea of encouraging new users to **search before posting**.  I also agree that most beginners questions have already been asked and answered.

**This community has already managed to build a great library of detailed questions and answers to most of basic programming related questions.**

But,

> The current search engine is far from good. It would need rebuilding

I disagree with this view. Since I have learnt [**how to properly use the SO search box**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), I find it very useful, quick, and to the point *(based on the actual search query)*.

I takes me a lot less time and clicks to find exactly what I need by composing a detailed query than to go through a few pages via google search(even if they redirect to SO). It's not the same google as a few years ago, now everything is somehow filtered. I don't want to go into details about how google engine work here as it would be off-topic but in general I really honestly prefer to use the internal SO search box.

I don't think it needs rebuilding at all. I think with a bit of more user-friendly [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) we could really expose the power of the SO search engine to everyone (including new users as well as veterans who never bothered using the internal search box).

Redirecting new users to the "HOW DO I SEARCH" once they click "ASK QUESTION" button would be worth giving a go. Say someone has already asked a question (or 2 or 5) and they have been well received by the community -> so that user doesn't get redirected to "HOW I SEARCH" and therefore is eligible of asking a new question directly. All other users should be encouraged to "SEARCH" before posting their (*almost always already answered*) question and I think most of the people here will agree with that.

Comment: If others agree then that's more than fine with me :) All I can say is that at least for me google will give me the result as item 1 90% of the time except in cases where special characters are involved. And in another 9% of the cases it's on page 1. But as I said, if others agree, then that's more than fine with me :D

Comment: @DavidMulder special characters are quite important in programming. Specially when you compose a query like "what does & mean"

Comment: I know, that's why I mentioned it explicitly ;-) Thing just is... I only come across those pesky queries like, I dunno, once every half year or so? Though it might be that with the languages you work they are a bigger deal.

Comment: But how many of our newcomers will readlly read that link ?

Answer (score -6):

I don't know if the front page necessarily factors into the workflow of new users – the 'Ask Question' button is on every page, after all. Instead, I think making the Ask Question page better at finding solutions is the solution.

Make the workflow start with choosing tags, to immediately highlight the most frequent questions. Consider the title as a search phrase, showing a search results page you need to click or scroll past before writing the question. Include Google-like blurbs, not just a flat title list.

Comment: The moment you get users in the 'Ask Question'-flow it's actually already too late, because a lot of users will already have decided to post their question at that point regardless of anything else. Not to say I don't agree that making the "Did you mean..." bigger would help a bit as well, but that's treating the symptoms rather than the actual problem.

Comment: @DavidMulder, and if they go to the front page they haven't? I'd like to see statistics on what users actually do, but I think integrating both searching and asking into a single flow is the most user friendly solution.

Comment: You're still thinking in the mindset that SO is just a Q&A site, by thinking like that users *will* keep posting lots of duplicates. If you consider SO a resource site where you can submit questions in case they haven't been asked yet you get an entirely different design pattern.

Comment: @DavidMulder, no, I'm considering SO as primarily a site where new users arrive through Google, and never visit the front page. Either they arrive at a solution immediately and never ask a question, or the one they find doesn't solve their problem and they may click 'Ask Question' *on that page*. Improving the front page does nothing to avoid duplicates from such users.

Comment: Ehm, did you read the proposal? It's proposing changing the look of the question pages as well by focusing more on search and making the ask question button/link secondary... It is not only limited to the front page. Additionally those users that arrive through Google are *likely* 'better' users than users which arrive through the front page.

Comment: @DavidMulder, I read it, but I disagree with hiding 'ask question' in questions, since I think that will just lead to posting (further) questions as answers, which is backwards. I also think (but don't know, see above about wanting statistics), that the vast majority of new users arrive through Google.

Comment: Not hiding it you know, the `placeholder` of the `input` motivates users to search for their problem. And if for whatever reason they don't want to search very much the link to ask a question is right there. But I agree, it would be interesting to see a rundown of users by source (homepage, google search for problem, etc.) vs percentage of questions closed.