# Why are there so many bad questions?

Tags: discussion, quality-improvement

I mostly lurk here and have been browsing some of my favorite tags. What I notice is the vast majority of questions are awful.

It's becoming a chore to wade through all of them because most of them are garbage. There are a couple of things that annoy me:

- Bad code formatting which makes it hard to read.
- Not even asking a question. Some questions I can't even tell what's asked.
- Not doing basic research. Is this site Google the answer overflow?

Is there anything that can be done to help improve post quality? It seems like Stack Overflow needs higher standards.

Comment: This is not a new problem. It doesn't seem to be detrimental. That said, **ideas** would be more welcome than simply pointing out a problem that everyone is aware of.

Comment: Questions are certainly far too important to this site to leave it up to people that often have no formal training, can't program themselves out of a paper bag and have no incentive to do it better.  Can you help and create more good ones?

Comment: @gnat how is that one a duplicate of this one? This question is not about hiding hideous questions, the one you link to is.

Comment: @CodeCaster per my reading, dupe target addresses the issue laid out here: "vast majority of questions are awful.

It's becoming a chore to wade through all of them because most of them are garbage"

Comment: @gnat _"Is there anything that can be done to help improve post quality?"_ -> _"Take the ostrich approach"_ is an _answer_, not a _duplicate_.

Comment: @CodeCaster duplicate _question_ hardly qualifies as ostrich, as addressing it eventually led to [meta-tag:triage] which is proactive solution

Comment: @gnat I'm running out of ways to tell you that _"How can we improve question quality"_ is not the same as _"How can I only see high-quality questions"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster triage shows that it's the same. When garbage is buried and stays visible only to reviewers, it makes the same effect as improving quality. Garbage questions that don't bother answerers are essentially nonexistent. Dupe targe question denoted the problem which was (is being) solved the way that addresses this very question

Comment: I'm not terribly impressed what comes out of the Triage and H&I queues lately btw, too much crap gets upvoted when it travels through them.  They do work with very low expectations I suppose.  Shocking how much effort is spent on them btw, Triage alone takes ~10000 reviews on 12000 questions per day.  You'd do wonder when they get to be actively harmful, generating views and votes on *only* the crap.

Comment: @hanspassant I can attest to this when you just finished sifting through 30+ utter trash posts in various queues, you find new appreciation for merely questionable content

Comment: All those who complain about SO mods/nazis/mobs/snobs being too harsh/hostile/unhelpful should have their account suspended until they have spent a month handling triage.  That would shut them up for sure.

Comment: @MartinJames That, or it'd just result in them upvoting and approving all the crap questions, because, "they're trying their best and it's not their fault if they're too lazy to google their question first."

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a dupe for this.

Comment: You might want to clarify this: "Is this site Google the answer overflow". There probably is a typo there, and the meaning is lost.

Comment: "people that often have no formal training, can't program themselves out of a paper bag" The stack exchange sites, as I understand it, are to provide a forum for answers. The people who need answers the most are those those who are the most ignorant. I don't generally suffer fools gladly either (although I take my turn at being one), but gently and patiently helping people to think critically and to clearly frame and articulate questions is going to help them become better programmers at least as much as much as offering an answer to a specific technical problem.

Comment: Creating good questions is not easy.  Even [OP](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5680735/user5680735) only has 0 of 6 SO questions rated higher than 1.

Comment: @mickeyf you are right.   That is how you can help:)   Now, what do you propose to do with the other 9999 incompetent developers who post rubbish every day?  I assume you wish to take them on too, to avoid charges of discrimination?  I hope you don't need any time off for work, food or sleep.   If I find out that you are not keeping up, I will flag you as unhelpful and hostile.

Comment: I lurk on Earth and have been reading the news. What I notice is that the vast majority of major events are awful. It's become heartbreaking to read and watch all of them. There are a couple things that disturb me: * People kill each other over stupid stuff * People ignore easy to fix problems * People believe demonstrably false things. Is there anything that can be done to save the human species? It seems like humanity needs hight standards.

Comment: 'gently and patiently helping people' NO!  No way am I wasting my free time on deadbeats.  I don't mind spending it on good questions, the rest can whistle.

Comment: Like this one? This has been asked millions of times.

Comment: @anatolyg he means Google-the-Answer Overflow. Like, you type your question into stack overflow and wait whole someone else googles it for you and pastes what they find into an answer.

Comment: I smell a sock puppet.

Comment: Joel spoke on this very issue recently at hack.summit(). Essentially, in order to have these nice things we have to be willing to self moderate, watch the queues and administer the site. The crap is part of it and it's our duties to do our due diligence to flag and remove it. No amount of controls or automation will ever fix human stupidity...yet.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon He's dreaming if he thinks that "self-moderation" can fix this without some rule changes. There are simply too many users now with enough reputation to up-vote bad questions, answer them, and up-vote terrible answers. But I agree that it isn't fixable through automation alone.

Comment: THIS is the prime example why I'm no longer posting on stackoverflow. You people are arrogant pseudo elite assholes that don't really know better and are enjoying to belittle those who need help. This community sucks.

Answer (score 83):

As a large site, it is inevitable that great masses of crap will be attracted. The only way to address this quality problem associated with scaling is by sacrificing quantity.

## We need to make it harder to create crap

It takes about 20 seconds right now to:

- Create an account (one click with Google)
- Ask a question (click the *very prominent* "Ask Question" button shown at the top of *every page* and click through the non-mandatory guidance text (forget about even taking a tour)
- Type a meaningless title like "HALP ME PLZ NOW" (the system does little to prevent this)
- Copy paste all your code and if you're being generous add the helpful problem statement "PLZ HALP ME CODE NO WORK I TRY EVERTING NEED BY TOMORROW"
- Click a suggested tag
- Click ask and get it published to *the front page of the site and tag pages*

The current system puts up zero resistance to the above procedure, only applying nominal penalties after the fact.

## We need to stop rewarding creating crap

Even the horrendous question above is likely to get answers. Eager answerers motivated by reputation and positive feedback will answer the question — after all, it is definitely answerable and *not NARQ* because it has some code, and maybe even a problem statement (implied…), right?

The quality level required to get answers, even answers that have non-trivial effort behind them — somebody pasted the code into their IDE and debugged it themselves for OP — is so tiny that Stack Overflow looks like a wasteland of a forum. Sure, high quality questions are getting good answers, but the skill being devoted to crap questions is simply wasted. We shouldn't be rewarding behavior like this. *We shouldn't allow bad questions, we shouldn't reward them, we shouldn't answer them, and we shouldn't reward answerers.*

## What should be done?

**We need to create barriers of entry that will disproportionately affect pseudo-programmers** that don't know how to debug and will abuse the site by using it to debug their code. This can be done by making the asking process more complicated by splitting the single textarea into separate ones for code, explanation, problem statement, problem analysis, etc. This makes it harder to just copy-paste crap into the box and have a valid question and would also have the side effect of guiding beginner users who *can* debug and would more likely be of value to the site. A more involved asking process adds resistance to drive by debug-help-getters, while not adding resistance or even decreasing complexity (in the form of reducing the required reading to write a good question) for salvageable users.

**We need to discourage low-quality content better** by penalizing bad questions proactively and disincentivizing answering them. **We already have a great machine learning algorithm to detect poor quality** (as described in podcast #60) which can be used to deprioritize or hide questions from the front page, tag pages, or search pages. This (and not *people* as evidenced by the failed Triage Queue) can also be used to find good questions that can be polished (by people). The average question, especially if it is from a new user or determined to likely be low quality should not go straight to the front page and be shown to answerers. These should go to moderation queues to allow for improvement or acceptance to be added to the site. We also need to apply incentivization in the right place, so you shouldn't get 25 rep from OP (accept and upvote) by answering a closed and negatively-voted question. Answers should only be for high quality questions; answers to questions that are closed and downvoted should not get rep.

**We need to make it easier to close and delete questions**. Most questions with three closevotes should be closed. Since the Type 1 error of closing is miniscule and questions can easily be reopened, because the Type 2 error of closing is enormous (the closevote queue alone is probably at around 200k questions without the shrinking algorithm) the Type 1 error should be increased to increase the power of the test. Decreasing the amount of closevotes needed to close a question to 3 from 5 would make the closing system faster and more efficient without sacrificing much Type 1 error. After closing, we should facilitate question deletion by allowing low-rep (i.e. <10k rep) users to recommend deletion, similar to the current functionality in the Low Quality Review Queue. Currently they have no means to voice how a question should be deleted. This would also apply to answers.

We need these system changes to let Stack Overflow focus on quality, which is suffering, over quantity, which we have too much of. We need to decrease the amount of questions on the site by weeding out the ones we *know* are of poor quality and raising the bar of quality. This will allow the talented base of Stack Exchange answerers to focus on the high-quality questions that will benefit us all, not just their asker.

There's nothing wrong with beginner questions, but there are only a limited number of these possible for each technology so now most of them are duplicates. The root problem is not programmers, rather it is coders who can't debug their code. These users are abusing the site and bringing down the quality level and are the ones that we should be targeting to disincintivize creating crap.

Comment: I'm not entirely behind your specific suggestions, but I upvoted for the general sentiment: make it harder to ask bad questions and make it easier to clean up after the ones that get through.

Comment: "The average question, especially if it is from a new user or determined to likely be low quality should not go straight to the front page and be shown to answerers. These should go to moderation queues to allow for improvement or acceptance to be added to the site." - this, _please this_.

Comment: The system actually *encourages* misspelling in question titles, due to the ban on duplicate titles. Your "HALP ME PLZ" made me laugh.

Comment: Separate text areas: they will just post their question into only one place. No rep closure: users will reopen bad questions. Mod queues: so basically exactly what triage is except with a new name and 100% entry. Easier closure: perhaps. Low rep deletion: get more rep, contributing is always an option. Overall, your ideas posted here read more like a small summary of certain other points that have been made for years - some of which have been put in place; all of which haven't made a dent in the amount of these types of questions.

Comment: @TravisJ I think we, as a site, need to put some effort into major reform, similar but perhaps opposite to the Summer of Love. A combination of site changes in addition to an overall change of attitude need to occur in the site for this to work. We need big changes to make people go from treating the site as a place for help to them treating the site as a repository of information that has a lasting benefit to multiple people. We can't just continue with status quo, this is a change in mindset.

Comment: Sorry, but you are woefully wrong with that mindset. It will only cause you personal anguish to try to push this behemoth in the changed direction. This site does work. It does. Arguing against that is a fool's errand. People do treat Stack Overflow as a repository of information that has a lasting benefit. Work on making your contribution of higher quality and that will help the site far more than trying to rip down the content of others.

Comment: @TravisJ You have completely misunderstood my post.

Comment: I really haven't. I have read posts and points like yours for *years*.

Comment: IMHO the best way to discourage asking bad questions is to discourage people to answer them. I agree that there should be no rep for answering a question which gets closed later. Also I think it would be a good idea to make questions asked by low rep users (for example <100 rep) require only 3 close votes to get closed. And there definitely should be a review queue which would allow <10k users to recommend deletion of closed questions.

Comment: Maybe worth checking out this proposal of mine from nearly two years ago: [Give greater dominance/placement to searching rather than asking for new/low rep users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261343/give-greater-dominance-placement-to-searching-rather-than-asking-for-new-low-rep). I think that's a far more realistic approach to solving a lot of problems, although your comment about 'very prominent "Ask Question" button' reminded me of it)

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it uses the Royal "we".  We, as in the community, can do nothing to implement these "what should be done" proposals.  Only *they* can do it.  Those *they* that barely even show up anymore, like I-shipped-the-T-shirts Tim.  Not here either, you'd be lucky that they even read it.  It is time that something is done about that, can only start if we aim correctly.

Answer (score 44):

I'm going to be using statistics from the week of October 8 to 14, 2017. There wasn't anything odd about that week as far as I can tell. Looking at a week avoids the weekend lull in asking that would come from looking at a day. That week there were about 145 million page views. A little less by [Quantcast numbers](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com):

[image: Quantcast]

And little more the Google Analytics numbers we include in the [site analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics) page available to [25k users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics). Both sources of traffic data estimate visits for the week at about 57 million. That could mean someone who came to get help with a problem they are trying to solve *or* someone who wants to participate on the site.

95% of those page visits are [via search](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources) (also a 25k-only link) and the vast majority of those are Google searches. (There's a chance some of those are people who type 'stackoverflow' in their browser's search bar. But those are potentially offset by the [miscategorization of duckduckgo.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258402/1438) traffic.) So we can guess that about 54 million of visits were from people who had some sort of problem they needed help with. (Could be more, of course. It's not unusual for me do one search after another while working on a coding project.)

There were 60,007 questions that week, which is about 1% of the search traffic. 2585 of those questions have been closed as duplicates so far, but it's likely that undercounts search failure by a large margin. Even so, it's obvious that most people who visit either find the answer they are looking for via search or give up before asking their question on Stack Overflow. We can certainly encourage people to do more searching, but it's not the most promising line of attack.

For [A/B testing we define "bad questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests) as those that have:

- a negative score (13,394) *or*
- been closed (6,127) *or*
- been deleted (8,042).

Altogether, there were 18,946 bad questions by that definition. (All of these numbers are from [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/746329/question-stats-for-a-week?start=2017-10-08). As always, please do your own analysis.) 32% badness a lot less than [Sturgeon's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law), but we can probably do better. I'd say we *have* done better as "badness" was much smaller (19%) [seven years ago](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/746329/question-stats-for-a-week?start=2009-10-08). But quite a bit of the increase in came from an increase in question downvoting as a result of [removing the reputation penalty](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

There are a number of [blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) and [filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error) in place to slow down askers and encourage them to ask better:

```
attempts    users  action                                                                  
--------    -----  ------
   60007    47914  asked
   13629     4743  Unformatted code
    9219     2987  Question with too much code and little context
    8770     3164  Question rejected due to low quality
    6285     3496  Question blocked
    5666     3925  CAPTCHA test failed
    5147     1396  New user question throttle
    1355      944  Question title word filter tripped
    1282      422  Post blocked for containing a link that requires code, without any code
     860      472  Post blocked for too many links
     449      187  Attempted to post duplicate question
     448      214  A post was blocked for having > 1 image
     216       53  Post blocked because IP blocked for spam
      58        6  Daily question limit reached
```

Clearly, these don't always prevent a bad question from landing on the site. When the system detects that the user has just dumped code in the body of the question, it gives this error:

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

But there's no way to systematically tell if added text is useful details or just words to get around the filter. That's the bad news. The good news is we can use this data to estimate the causes of bad questions:

1. Code dumps
2. Grammar, spelling and other ["quality" problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error)
3. [Problem titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/the-efficacy-of-stack-overflows-question-title-filter)
4. Misusing links
5. Asking too many questions or [too many poor questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited) too quickly

Once the system has a pretty good idea that a user is not going to ask good questions, it starts [blocking that user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans). In that week, 3496 users were prevented from asking at least once. We've made it harder to bypass the block by creating a new account, but it obviously happens sometimes.

Ultimately, we have millions of people visiting the site. While there are many prompts, blocks and limits slowing down questions, the small percentage of visitors who make it through turns out to be a large absolute number. For better or worse, the barriers to asking mean that the most determined (or, perhaps, desperate) users actually post. I'm sure you know decent programmers who have no interest in posting on Stack Overflow because of our reputation for harsh criticism. Those folks don't ask, but probably would produce better than average questions. Meanwhile, the people who just don't care about anything but the chance to get help from a programmer are willing to put up with just about any crap we throw at them.

---

One theory that people often raise when it comes to the cause of bad questions is that we could reduce the problem by just not answering bad questions. There's a good deal of sense in that argument. Research on [artificial societies](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2002/04/seeing-around-corners/302471/) does suggest that a relatively small amount of reinforcement can encourage undesirable behavior in a population. Bad questions are answered about 28% of the time compared to 53% for all questions. Depending on what you value, asking on Stack Overflow with 28% might be worth putting up with even more filters, blocks, warnings, downvotes, critical comments and so on.

A good way to prevent people from answering bad questions would be to [close them more quickly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286407/thought-experiment-what-would-happen-if-we-didnt-have-close-votes). But another way would be to increase the absolute number of *good, answerable* questions. Think about [why people answer questions](http://jericson.github.io/2016/07/13/QA_economics.html). If you have a bit of time and would like to help someone out or earn reputation, you might look around for a Stack Overflow question to answer. Sorting by upvotes will show you good questions that probably already have answers or, if not, are difficult to solve. These aren't likely to be productive in terms of helping others or reputation, so answerers need to look further down the list to find unanswered (but answerable) questions.

I think most users would rather answer good questions, but don't feel their contributions will be worthwhile. I certainly noticed that about myself when I first started contributing to Stack Overflow and, more recently, when I [tried to get a sock puppet to 1k](http://jericson.github.io/2017/07/26/race_to_1k_1.html). Adding filters and blocks and warnings have signalled to sensible people who can read the signs that we don't want their questions. We are running out of obstacles we can throw in people's ways. So that's why I'm glad we are tackling the other end of the problem: [encouraging askers to post more useful questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions).

---

Some people have [expressed surprise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions/358250?noredirect=1#comment529060_358250) that so many asking attempts have been blocked. This isn't really anything new:

[image: Question attempts blocked percentage]

For those who are curious, the spike in June and July of 2016 came from the "Post blocked for too many links" filter. Basically, spam. Other than that, the most common hurdle for people is posting unformatted code. (Again, the data from October 8 to 14, 2017 is typical in this regard.) I didn't dig into the data to be sure, but I suspect most of those folks eventually get around the block by either fixing their code formatting or fiddling with the text of the question until the algorithm is satisfied. Either way, we can do better.

Comment: Ik makes me sad that this is now a late answer which is not very visible. Seems like a bit of a waste of your time and effort invested here.It gives me the idea the site is missing a feature, one that lists new answers rather than only updated questions.

Comment: We have that feature, @Gimby. The home page displays all questions with recent activity, including new answers. It's how I found this gem of an answer a few moments ago.

Comment: @CodyGray well I guess the tiny "answered X hours ago" link is kind of okay as it directly takes you to the answer. I always overlook that little feature and then I make my life difficult by going to the question and having to scroll around to find the recent answer(s).

Comment: @Gimby: This isn't really an answer I could have written even a few months ago. Documentation and the 1k puppet experiment were really eye-opening for me. The good news is I plan to link to it like crazy in the next few months.

Comment: > _"Let's define "bad questions" as those that have:"_ - also count those with any number of close votes. Since the queue is overloaded, only a fraction of the deserving questions is actually getting closed. (Well, you can subtract from these the average percentage of questions that get the "leave open" verdict.)

Comment: This answer has a fundamental problem: bad questions are often upvoted, open, and not deleted. This problem is even worse now that close votes age away. Not having a good definition of "bad question" aside from random passerbys' button clicking makes it difficult to trust any analysis. Note that we can't trust random passerbys, as we have no idea whether their criteria align with SO's goals of being a knowledge repository or how careful their evaluation was.

Comment: @Gimby, what you refer to is the [Fastest Gun in the West problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/364344), and it definitely still exists, but I think it is getting better.

Comment: @NH Uh, maybe you posted that comment in the wrong place? Mentioning FGIW here makes no sense.

Comment: @Gimby, your first comment about late answers not being visible.

Answer (score 27):

> Is there anything that can be done to help improve post quality?

Yes, but we want *your* help, too.

> Bad code formatting which makes it hard to read.

Suggest an edit for it.  Since you're below 2K rep, your edits will go into the queue.  I'd be willing to bet there's more to fix in the question as well, so please feel encouraged to edit the rest of question into shape.

> Not even asking a question. Some questions I can't even tell what's asked.

Flag it for closure.  You have over 15 rep and that vote will help get bad questions off of the site faster.

> Not doing basic research.

Downvote it (but you need at least 125 reputation).

There are a lot of users who are dedicated to improving the question and answer quality out here, but by and large the ability to impact that has been afforded to us through our privileges.  All we need to do is use them effectively.

Comment: How does a user get to 2000+ rep and post this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779327/using-hyperlinks-to-navigate-to-several-places-in-a-wpf-application and not even ask a question?  Should I comment, "hey what is your question", downvote, flag, or just move on even though I can answer what I believe the question is?  However, if I answer it and there is no question, I am not helping, and potentially others on SO will down vote ME because although I am trying to help, I didn't answer the specific question.  If we can't fix this for 2000+ rep people, how will we fix for on newer folks?

Comment: @KoryGill If you click on the user's username you can see what they have done on this site. In this case, the user appears to be good at answering ANTLR questions.

Comment: @KoryGill What you're doing, which is targeting a specific user and making assumptions is very poor. Vote on the post, not on the user nor the reputation.

Comment: @Tunaki, thank you for the feedback.  Personally, I would expect more people on SO as their rep increases and the time they have been a member; as I recall when you gain certain privileges on the site the SO notifications remind you that you are now an ambassador and are held to a higher standard.  That said however, it was not my intention to target or pick on the OP in my example, but I can tell you that lack of quality was my first thought when I was reading the OP's question, and saw this thread on my right sidebar.

Comment: @Tunaki: Kory Gill doesn't appear to be targeting the user. They simply pointed out an objectively bad question by a user who seemingly ought to know better than to be posting such questions. They're not dismissing a good or mediocre question as bad just because it's coming from an established user.

Answer (score 18):

Stack Overflow was created by competent developers for competent developers. As such, certain assumptions were made. One of them was that everybody should be treated equally, regardless of their contribution (or not) to the site.

This worked in the site's early days because the vast majority of users were competent developers who were interested in sharing their knowledge. Stupid questions from clueless morons did appear, but they were the exception rather than the norm, and because of their relative rarity they were quickly expunged. Thus the overall quality of the site remained high.

The picture changed as SO transitioned from a niche site for competent developers to a one-stop shop for programming questions. More and more users joined who were only interested in getting answers to their generally, very specific, questions and that altered the balance so that competent programmers were no longer in the majority. That meant, proportionately, there were far more low-quality questions for the competent programmers to moderate - the trickle had become a tide. And as many including yourself have noticed, there just aren't enough people to manage the tide that is growing larger every day.

The only way to fix the quality issue is to accept that **not all Stack Overflow users are created equal**, and amend the site's policies accordingly. Egalitarian principles need to go out the window. Users who consistently ask poor questions, who post poor answers, who don't participate in moderation - need to be separated from the competent developers who **add value** to the site. Otherwise the competent developers will go elsewhere.

Unfortunately, the management of SO is unwilling to add such tiers because it will affect their monetisation policies. Even more unfortunately, this short-sighted viewpoint will eventually cause Stack Overflow to end up as yet another low-quality cesspool like the sites such as Experts Exchange that are so derided around here.

Due to this, I'm extremely pessimistic about Stack Overflow's long-term future for competent developers. At this point I feel that the best option is for us to build our own version of the site, with all the checks and balances that SO doesn't have, to ensure that quality is maintained.

Comment: To be fair, the management *has* done some of this. There are rolling question limits and even bans for people who have demonstrated that they "consistently ask poor questions" and "who post poor answers." That reduces the garbage, but doesn't keep it from being a cesspool. There are hundreds of new idiots signing up every hour. We need much better ways to dispatch crap than "queues."

Comment: @CodyGray Rolling question limits and bans aren't enough, hence my mention of "tiers", i.e. separating what users can do and see based on their reputation. Even having an option "hide all questions from new users and those under 100 reputation" would go a long way to removing the frustration for competent developers who use the site - but it still doesn't address the underlying issue of low quality.

Comment: I'm actually not sure that's true. I see just as many bad questions from people with moderate reputation levels (*easily* anywhere between 500 and 2k) as I do from brand-new users or those under 100. Aside from that, the resistance to tiering the site has been that you are effectively *ensuring* that the lower tiers are going to be festering shit-holes. No one will ever want to go there. There would be no realistic way for new users who just happened to be competent to move up. I still think we need better content-management tools, not a way to bury the crap where it's harder to see.

Comment: @CodyGray "There would be no realistic way for new users who just happened to be competent to move up." I agree 100% - that sort of policy would ironically bar the person who asked this question, who seems to be one of the competent developers we want on the site. But I'm not claiming this is "the solution" to the site's problems, maybe a possible approach. What I think you and I disagree on is the problem of bad content - at the end of the day, it's bad users that create that bad content, and unless you do something about those users, all the mod tools in existence won't be enough.

Comment: "Members are different than users... a core group arises that cares about and gardens effectively... The core group has rights that trump individual rights in some situations. This pulls against the libertarian view that's quite common on the network, and it absolutely pulls against the one person/one vote notion. But you can see examples of how bad an idea voting is when citizenship is the same as ability to log in..." Will be really funny to see SO fail having [author of this quote](http://www.shirky.com/writings/group_enemy.html "Clay Shirky") in their board of directors

Comment: Another idea from the paper that gnat quoted: _just turn off account registration_: «That's a way of raising the bar, that's creating a threshold of participation. And anyone who bookmarks that page and says 'You know, I really want to be in there; maybe I'll go back later,' that's the kind of user [we] want to have.» I agree with the majority of this answer, but I also think that Cody Gray is right: tiers are not going to solve it, unless there's only two, read-write and read-only.

Answer (score 6):

I came across this question and thought I'd chime in as I can recognize that in many cases I may be what many of you are complaining about so a noob perspective might at least give some insight.

I'm not sure that my usage of Stack Overflow is what it was designed for but will say that it has been helpful in learning.  My first exposure to SO was from using Google to find a solution to a problem. From what I recall, I found a post from here that was doing something similar to what I wanted. Looking at my first post, it was a poor question with many of the problems listed above. That being said I did learn from it and was sure to include what I'd tried in my other posts. I'd say the goal of any post I make is to accomplish the task I'm working on but to also learn enough to be able to accomplish the same thing on my own in the future.  This site has been wonderful for that. I would still say that I am a beginner but I'm trying. I'm never posting things without researching and trying other things.

To answer the original question: I'd assume that the majority of bad questions arise because someone did use Google and the results brought them here and like others have said it's pretty easy to ask a question. While it would be ideal for someone to know the forum's question etiquette before posting I don't think that will ever happen. I think building the compliance into the asking format as @bjb568 suggests above would cut down on a lot of the bad questions though. Using my first post as an example, if there was a box for "what have I tried", errors, etc. I would have included that.

Answer (score 6):

> Not doing basic research. Is this site Google the answer overflow?

If you have any research skills, you will usually find the answer to your own question.  The obvious corollary is that almost all the boring, easy,  RTFM / easily-searchable questions come from people who are terrible at searching, or didn't even try.  (The rest tend to be the occasional total misreading of something that gets someone totally confused.)

I've answered more than half the [(very few) questions I've posted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes?tab=questions&sort=votes).  Some of them were originally designed as a Q&A writeup of [something I thought was worth sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377711/which-2s-complement-integer-operations-can-be-used-without-zeroing-high-bits-in).  Another couple were ones I ended up solving after [thinking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468465/does-a-function-with-instructions-before-the-entry-point-label-cause-problems-fo) or right away [after a search that I didn't expect was going to find anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently).  Most people that post good answers hardly ever ask questions.

---

I'm all for some kind of system to guide new users into a search for things that are similar to their problem.  I agree that asking a question is too easy.  There can and should be more automated searching for stuff that's similar to their question.

I'd love to see something like an AI-guided FAQ that directed people towards existing Q&As.

I'd also like to see some checkboxes that you have to tick before posting, that say

- yes, I've searched
- yes, I've used a debugger on my code.
- yes, I've commented and explained the code I'm posting

(with the latter two only showing if someone posts what looks like code to some heuristic.)

Answer (score 5):

The more popular Stack Overflow becomes, the more low quality posters it attracts.

It's not only true for Stack Overflow. It's true for any sites on the Internet. Some people, who started a YouTube channel for example, need to close comments when the channel becomes famous.
Why? Because it tends to attract trolls, people not providing valuable adds to the video, etc.

As a user, I think it can be a new challenge for Stack Overflow.

However, some tools are already offered. Gain some reputation points and you'll be able to:

- **50+**:  Post a comment under bad question asking politely OP to improve its post (constructive criticism)
- **125+**: Downvote
- **2k+**:  Edit instantly any kind of bad questions (need peers review first under 2k)
- **3k+**:  Vote for closing bad questions

I don't like downvoting for the following reasons:

> - It raises number of inactive accounts
> - It can scare OP from posting **forever**
> - It can make the site appear like an elitist land

References:

- [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: The tools you mention do not prevent bad quality questions to be posted, hardly ever improve them and won't prevent people who use Stack Overflow as their resume to post answers that may or may not help the OP.

Comment: @CodeCaster, They do (sort-of) thwart bad questions. Closevotes, downvotes, all feed the question ban system, which is supposed to prevent users from posting many bad questions.

Comment: [Off topic questions have to be cleared out of the way, but NOT via closure](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251897/839601)

Comment: Regarding downvotes: "It hurts your own reputation" - no downvotes on questions are free, and have been for a long time. Downvoting questions does not cost you any rep. "It scares OP away, makes the site appear elitist" - So does closing their question. And if people post a bad question which gets downvoted, it's quite likely that the next question will be just as bad, and if we scare then away, then we have successfully kept out their next bad question. If we leave a comment with our DV, it will help them understand what's wrong with their question, and how they can make the next one better.

Comment: @JonasCz This is why I prefer an amical approach made of edit and comment before closing, downvoting or comment with DV.

Comment: @Stephan what is the pont of an amical approach to someone who WANTS THEIR HOMEWORK ANSWER NOW WHY ARE YOU POSTING THSE STUPID COMMENTS WHY DONT YOU JUST ANSWER MY QUESTION I SPENT 30 SECONDS OF MY VALUABLE TIME COPYPASTING IT TO SO WHY DONT YOU JUST ANSWER IT ARE YOU SO STUPID?  JUST ANSWER IT AND STOP TALKING BACK IF YOU DONT KNOW THE ANSWER JUST GO AWAY....  Sadly, most of the time, being nice just get you abused:(

Comment: I do agree, however, that downvotes are pretty useless when applied to 'Member since today' homework vamps.  They use a new account for each question anyway.  Close-votes are better, but you need to be quick before some rep-personalServicesWorker answers, the OP copies out the answer and deletes his/her question to attempt to hide the Q&A from their prof/TA.

Comment: @MartinJames The downvote isn't there to hurt the OP, it's there to provide a signal to every other viewer, or potential viewer, that the question isn't a good one.  That it will, on rare occasion, actually stop someone from being able to ask a bad question when enough of their posts are downvoted is nice, but not the main reason to downvote.

Comment: I'm gonna say that being harsh and angry to people isn't going to help.  I've been on here a year,  appreciate the help I've gotten,  but also feel like "why bother?" answering questions because a lot of folks (commentets, not the OP) are harshly critical if your answer isn't PERFECT.

Comment: For the lazy OPs, link to a Google search, or LMGTFY. No need to be mean.  They'll get the hint.  Maybe.  But if someone's really struggling, give then a hand and encouragement and less attitude,  please!

Comment: Many of then dont want a hand, or encouragement, THEY WANT THEIR QUESTION ANSWSERED NOW HOW MANY TIMES DO I HAVETO SAY THIS JUST ANSWER THE BLOODY QUESTION AND STOP WITH THE COMMENTS I HAVE TO HAND THIS IN TOMORROW JUST ANSWER THE QUESTION AND STOP COMPLAINING ELSE I WILL FLAG YOUR COMMENTS AS HOSTILE AND GET YOU SUSPENDED.  YOU CANT DO NOTHIN TO ME COS I JUST CREATE NEW ACCOUTS SO DO MY WORK AND DO IT NOW OR JUST GO AWAY GOD YOURE SO STUPID ON SO BLOODY SO-CALLED EXPERTS CANT JUST DO WHAT I WANT.

Comment: A significant set of question posters, as well as being selfish and incompetent deadbeats, blatantly lie in their questions, eg. asking why the output is X when the code they post will not remotely compile because they typed in the code from their printed homework and transcribed it wrong.

Comment: The two last cases also apply for CLOSING.

Comment: [A Close Vote is not a Super-Downvote. Please don't use it as one.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5498/95920) The flow is not Close -> Downvote. It may not even be Downvote -> Close. They are different tools for different, but sometimes overlapping, situations.

Comment: Funny enough, closing tends to be less discouraging than downvoting. So depending on what your goal is, you may find one or the other more productive. Sadly, an awful lot of folks close when their goal is better served by downvoting, and then get unhappy when it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, additional barriers for asking would be helpful.

Since this site is about **programming**, I would appreciate a **code requirement** at least for new users.

If we allow posting questions only if:

1. the user has over 500 reputation *or*
2. it includes a code fragment and is not too-similar to other questions (in particular of the same user!)

So for "existing" users nothing really would change. Only new users need to put more effort into their questions and covey more of the site focus. Actually, this may even make the *experience better for them*. Right now, many post a question, it is closed as duplicate or off-topic, and they are annoyed. Assisting them with writing a better question (or *searching* better) may be the better user experience.

Comment: Plenty of poor questions have code in them, and plenty of good questions have little or no code, so I don't see this requirement as an improvement.  Also, "not too similar" just leads to adding garbage and removing potentially-useful information, in the same way spam posts include random text to defeat naive spam filters.

Comment: Well, I see many more non-code poor questions. "Where can I find a library to do xyz" for example. So for the first question it may help. As for the too-similar filter, adding random tokens is easy for a spam bot; but we are having human users here. Instead of banging at their keyboard to add random garbage, they might actually look at the linked questions and either see their question being answered, or attempt to explain the differences. But right now, it's easier to click send, than to click the suggested similar questions.