# Can we add the Stack Snippet editor to the Ask Question Wizard?

Tags: feature-request, ask-question-wizard-2018

Is it possible to add the traditional tools to the ask question wizard? Not having it in the wizard requires someone to ask the question in a poorly formatted version and then after posting it going back to edit it using the traditional tools.

The main issue here is the code tool[image: Code tool]

This little bundle of joy makes it super easy to add code that is nicely formatted and as well provide code highlighting to your post but in the image below not having access to this and instead having these guides that tell you how to format your code creates a bad UX in my opinion and nobody who joins up(since this is targeted at new users) is going to probably spend the time to properly format their question. Which in turn may result in the question being poorly received.

[image: Ask wizard]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381887

Comment: That aside, since code fence is available now and listed in the documentation, if someone is not going to spend time to type 6 backticks then they are doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: @user202729, I have never yet used 6 backticks (3 and 3 in series) in either of my posts ;) Only old good 4 spaces everywhere..

Comment: @Sinatr Of course I meant 3 open and 3 close...

Comment: I much prefer the snippet editor to backticks and ive used both quite a bit @user202729

Answer (score 4):

If you click down to the second expandy thingy, you'll see some instructions on how to code. It's where your code belongs in the template, so we don't show that hint until you get there. The "Review" stage shows the standard set of buttons, including the code formatting button.

That said, we are looking at adjustments to the wizard and I'll pass your feedback on to the developers.

Comment: Thats what I was getting at it gives you instructions on how to do it but it would be more beneficial to just have the tool thats used in the traditional view

Comment: I'd like to look at the data to see if the wizard is failing to help users format their code correctly compared to when we had just the traditional ask page. My hunch is that the icon is less helpful than the JIT guidance. If there's a change, I suspect it'll turn up in the ratio of ["Unformatted code" blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358412/1438).

Comment: Okay, that's one UV for "expandy thingy"

Comment: @user202729: Unfortunately, [the snippet feature](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) is only useful if you happen to be asking a JavaScript (or CSS or HTML). I think it would be helpful to include instructions on using it if the asker picks one of those tags. Otherwise, people are better off using Markdown code blocks instead. We're doing some research on this aspect of the Wizard in preparation for another round of updates.

Comment: @JonEricson the snippet editor makes formatting code easier because you can use tabs and you can simply change the desired language in the text field once finished this is how I always add code into a post and using the guided mode was especially frustrating due to not having it

Comment: @CoderJoe: Since I wrote this answer, we've been batting around some ideas for how we might reduce frustration with getting code into questions. Not being able to use tab is certainly something we've considered. ([Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation) had an editor that allowed using tab, for instance.) Honestly, our editor is looking shabby after 10+ years. It's probably time we considered refreshing it too.

Comment: I would +1 that idea the fact this website is for programming specific questions adding code to a post should be super easy and seamless with any language..which is currently is not and very inconsistent across the site(use backticks here, 8 spaces here, editor here)