# Search bar should be more prominent

Tags: feature-request, search-box

I'm not stating anything new when I say that SO has a problem with many, many duplicate questions, as well as a large number of low quality questions.

When users ask new questions, we currently try to steer them to existing good questions by recommending related or duplicate questions as they are typing. What if we could catch them before they hit Ask Question in the first place?

I noticed today, possibly because of the recent redesign, that the Ask Question button is far more prominent than the Search bar. For new users, in fact, the Search bar is almost completely dwarfed by the Sign Up apparatus. Here is what the entry page looks like on a virgin (never logged in to SO) browser:

[image: tiny search bar, half screen sign up offer, large Ask Question button]

As you can see, the eye is drawn first to the half-screen sign up form, and then to the blue Ask Question button immediately below that. The subtle Search bar, light gray and located above the area of the screen the user has already looked at, fades into the background.

For a logged-in user, it's not much better:

[image: Top Questions, Ask Question, and tiny gray Search bar]

The large font of "Top Questions" and the blue background of the "Ask Question" button draw one's eye to that area of the screen, and again the Search bar is overlooked.

This might be a pipe dream, but with the volume of already-answered questions that are already in the SO corpus, wouldn't we prefer to steer new (and returning) users to the Search bar rather than the Ask Question button?

**TL;DR**: **Search** should stand out more than **Ask Question**.

Comment: Yes, i totally agree with you. First of all, our generation is too lazy to actually go and search for answers and would rather prefer straight asking before researching and this is one of the reason why search bar is overlooked often.

Comment: "Ask Question" should only appear at the bottom of the search results page.

Comment: When the search field is 'active' a blue magnifying glass button shows up. I would suggest as an easy fix that this is made the default state of the search field. (In fact, I wonder if perhaps it would even make sense to move the "ask question' button up into the tool bar between  search and avatar)

Comment: Ironically, I searched MetaSO using several different search terms and did not find [this older question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261343/give-greater-dominance-placement-to-searching-rather-than-asking-for-new-low-rep?rq=1) which is basically the same question asked against an older version of the UI.